# JS image source attribute to trigger action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  in a (steep) learning cuve with JS. I would suppose my JS code will only trigger action for image with src attribute : "http://placehold.it/350x150" to change to the targeted new link (320x120) on click. but it changes ALL images to the latest, any idea plz ?

Complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/celiostat/nmH8L/34/

HTML:

```
<img class=icon1 src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img class=icon2 src="http://placehold.it/140x140"/>
<img class=icon3 src="http://placehold.it/200x100"/>
<img class=icon4 src="http://placehold.it/350x65"/>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.icon3').on("click", function() {
    if($('img').attr('src') === 'http://placehold.it/350x150')
        $('img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/300x120');
})
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to resume back the former image to it's initial state, then for each click event you should do the following.

```
$('.icon1').on("click", function (e) {
    if ($(e.currentTarget).attr('src') === 'http://placehold.it/350x150') {
        var changedImage = $('[data-image-name="changed_image"]')
        changedImage.removeAttr('data-image-name').attr('src', changedImage.attr('prevSrc'));
        $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-image-name', 'changed_image');
        $(e.currentTarget).attr('prevSrc', 'http://placehold.it/350x150');
        $(e.currentTarget).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/300x150');
    }
})
```

Comment: When you'll click on any image, it's src will be change and when you click any other image the previous image will be restored to the initial state, is that what you want? Then its working is jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/nmH8L/77/

Answer (score 1):

`$('img')` selects all image elements. Use `$(this)` to get the element the event fired on.

Comment: @lauWM You also need to have the right elements selected for `on("click")`. Currently you're only selecting the third icon, not all of them.  Try `$('img').on("click" ...);`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('image').on("click", function() {
    if($('img').attr('src') === 'http://placehold.it/350x150')
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/300x120');
    })
})
```

Comment: ok cool works !..now I need to figure out how to duplicate this among other images, idea being that if i click another image, the former image would resume back to its initial state.. any help is welcomed!cheers